# Unable to cleanup PKI, error file not found: CADescription

Tags: pki, ca

When trying to clean up my PKI by running certutil -deleterow 31/12/2018 Cert I receive the following error:

```
C:\windows\system32>certutil -deleterow 31/12/2018 Cert
437.625.0:<2020/12/29, 11:55:22>: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): CADescription
437.625.0:<2020/12/29, 11:55:22>: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): ParentCAName
410.8311.0:<2020/12/29, 11:55:22>: 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER): 31/12/2018
410.8330.0:<2020/12/29, 11:55:22>: 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
410.8345.0:<2020/12/29, 11:55:22>: 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER): 31/12/2018
Rows deleted: 0
CertUtil: -deleterow command completed successfully.
```

No certs have been cleaned although there are more than enough that should be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep the date format at "certutil -deletrow %date% Request" command same as your request submission date.
Example:
in my failed request the Request submission date was: 2021-01-12
I run the "certutil -deletrow 2021/01/12 Request", and it worked, all failed requests till January 12, 2021 have been deleted/cleaned up.